# popup contact form with validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to create popup contact form with validation like i did here `http://89.212.111.174/delovtujini.si` and click “VPIS V BAZO”.

You will get popup where you can fill contact form. How can i do this with CI? Here on this example i do everything in the same html page. In CI i try to create new controller for contat form but i dno’t know how to open the window. I also try to use http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ I try. but none solution works.

Can someone explain me how to do? Maybe is better to use https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Ajax-Framework-For-CodeIgniter

Thx

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 ways to trackle your issue.

1) Use custom inline lightbox like what is done on

```
http://89.212.111.174/delovtujini.si
```

First post the form back to the same page like below:

```
public function sign_up()
{
    // Setup form validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules(array(
        //...do stuff...
    ));

    // Run form validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        //...do stuff...
        redirect('');
    }

    // Load view
    $this->load->view('my_form');
}
```

In the view when you detect a POST you must have javascript
to "open" the lightbox on page load since it won't be display by default (i.e. when you load the page normally the lightbox is "closed" and it is "opened" only when the button is clicked.)

2) Use a iframe lightbox

create the form on a separate CI controller/view and display in within an iframe when the button is clicked.
when the form is submitted you can then call javascript to close the lightbox.

3) Use ajax
both inline and iframe lightbox can work with an ajax form
the idea the same as using an iframe lightbox. Once the form is submitted via ajax, use javascript to close the lightbox.